# Download and play video from web on Blackberry

Tags: networking, video, blackberry, mmapi

I want to play video from a url in my application... I want to first stream the video and store the data in a buffer and then feed the data from the buffer to the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bufferedplaybackdemo sample in BlackBerry Eclipse Plugin, for audio. I do believe it's not hard to rewrite it for video playback.

See [Buffer and play streamed media](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8542/Buffer_and_play_streamed_media_740033_11.jsp)

Comment: yes i am using this sample for playing videos..but the problem i am facing is that videos are indeed played..but i  cant see the video of it...i can only hear the audio...